# What is hotkey to manually check a C function api in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes when I write the function name, the api is shown above its name automatically, but sometimes it doesn't work and I have to rewrite the function name to get that, so is there a shortcut key for it?

(I know `man function_name` but I used to `CTRL+Q` in NetBeans to get the same thing quickly but I can't find one for vscode.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ALT+F12` seems to do the job. It's called "peek definition" which is available in the right click options too.

Also note that the opened window doesn't go away by clicking somewhere else outside of it, however, instead you can still use the `ESC` from keyboard.